# Custom drawing in Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, drawing

Is there a custom drawing that is available for Windows Store, similar to DrawingVisual in WPF?

My case is, I have around 100 'buttons' that are comprised of 3 textblocks each (1 a checkmark, 1 for a description, 1 for an expand button). We use a lot of data templates and use DataTemplateSelector to select the items so I'm not sure if Virtualization is gonna work.

What I would like to achieve is, use custom drawing to 'draw' the 10 buttons, or even 1 button to lessen the layouting performed. In this way, hopefully we improve the performance significantly.

Is such a thing possible in Windows Store App development?

Thank you!

Comment: There are a few ways to draw basic shapes - with a `Shape` or more typically `Path` element or using some Direct2D, but you don't really want to do that for buttons since you'll need to write all the input handling, accessibility etc. that's already done for you in the platform. Unless you don't actually really need a button...
Virtualization should work in such cases and someone might be able to help you if you shared a bit more details about your code. Are your buttons organized in some kind of a list control (which by default virtualize their data containers)?

Comment: Yes, they are under an ItemsControl, but unfortunately, I don't think Virtualization is going to help as I have nested ItemsControl (2 levels of Collection), which I read will automatically turn off Virtualization.

Comment: ItemsControl doesn't do virtualization since it doesn't have a ScrollViewer in its template. You could use a ListView instead. Nesting controls doesn't disable virtualization unless your layout is more like a grid scrollable in two dimensions, which is where you'd need to implement your own virtualization or look for a DataGrid-like control.

Comment: Hmm, I wrap the ItemsControl inside a ScrollViewer but use a StackPanel in the ItemsPanelTemplate. If I just replace it to VirtualizingStackPanel, will that work? I tried using ListView but then the Horizontal Scrollbar disappears.

Comment: That won't work. ItemsControl doesn't support virtualization. Neither does StackPanel. ListView, ListBox and GridView do. You can set ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility and HorizontalScrollMode on a ListView to get it to show the horizontal scroll bar if you're OK with virtualizing just vertically. It might be enough for your scenario. Otherwise - you could manually visualize horizontally while allowing the ListView to handle vertical virtualization. You could also nest a ListView in each item but that might be inefficient. Ideally you'd need two dimensional virtualization - DataGrid..